# How do you compiling cs file modification on a deployed website? Is it possible?

Tags: asp.net

If this has been asked before, I apologize.

If I had a currently deployed ASP.Net C# website which had a slight bug or modification needed in a cs file, would it be possible to modify the cs file and have IIS recompile the ASP.Net website rather than using Visual Studio or SharpDevelop to rebuild the site?

I'm familiar with PHP websites where a change is compiled automatically. Is there a way to get ASP.Net or IIS to do something similar to the code-behind files of an ASP.Net website?

I understand that modifying the web.config file may force a recompile, and modifying the ASPx files automatically displays the changes, but I haven't found the same success in the code behind files.

Thank you.

**Edit (Answer below):**

The command to recompile an existing ASP.Net website using existing sources (including the solution file) is this:

```
%windir%\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild /m Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
@IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO err
@exit /B 0
:err
@PAUSE
@exit /B 1
```

Paste the above code into a batch file within your solution directory. Change the Solution.sln to your solution file, modify the framework to match your installed version. You can change the Configuration option to "Release" as well.

* Batch file code used from SharpDevelop source code. Idea based on this forum post: http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/8281.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command to recompile an existing ASP.Net website using existing sources (including the solution file) is this:

```
%windir%\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild /m Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
@IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO err
@exit /B 0
:err
@PAUSE
@exit /B 1
```

Paste the above code into a batch file within your solution directory. Change the Solution.sln to your solution file, modify the framework to match your installed version. You can change the Configuration option to "Release" as well.

* Batch file code used from SharpDevelop source code. Idea based on this forum post: http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/8281.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you deploy web site as .aspx and .cs files, it is compiled automatically whenever you put there a newer file. It is compiled when the first web client requests something. I use this feature often for my noncommercial websites, because it is much faster to upload a single file than to redeploy a whole web site from scratch.

Comment: Along with this: If you have deployed a compiled site (ie: has a bin directory where the code is compiled into assemblies) then you can just deploy the updated assembly.

Comment: What if you decide to change an existing cs file? Does IIS recompile it? I haven't found that to be true. - @Chris, regarding the compiled assembly, I may not have made it clear that I would not have VS or SharpDevelop to rebuild the site.

Comment: Buckwheat: Yes, it is recompiled on each cs file change. Don't worry. :-)

Comment: Al: After some testing I could not verify what you said. I will continue to see if I can force a recompile but changing the cs files had no effect.

Comment: Please don't tell me that you put there a new or changed .cs file and the web application continued to run with the old file. I can't believe it, because I always do it like with PHP - any file can be changed anytime and the application is recomplied automatically. I use current ASP.NET version 4.

Comment: Al, yes they did continue to run with the old file because the site was not recompiled by IIS. This may be a misconfiguration in IIS or the web.config but I've seen the same results in IIS 5, 6 and 7. I've added a solution to the original question that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.net works complety different to the way tath does PHP

- PHP is interpreted purely like javascript
- ASP.net is compiled in middle language and later interpreted like Java

the code behind code is compiled in a dll and interpreted by ASP VM in your webpage; how this code is compiled in a DLL you can add the bugfixes on-the-fly like PHP , you need to reopen the project and recompile the web project if you won't ,uninstall the web application and reinstall the new.

compile the project with the bugfixes in release mode copy the dll of your main project named [nameof your project].dll and copy into the folder bin inside the folder of your application in the web server ... that should works ... if don't the recompile and uninstall /install your app again ...

sorry but its one of the incoveniences of this plataform

Comment: Thanks. This answer pretty much verified my findings. In summary, once the website is compiled into the DLL you would have to use VS and open the solution, then rebuild the solution to see the changes. This makes it difficult to modify client projects.

Comment: Note that you CAN precompile web site, but it is not mandatory. If you expect that you will need to do changes, you can deploy web site in source form and then it works like PHP - although it is compiled, you can change particular files later and it gets recompiled automatically.

Comment: I've added the solution to the original question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Al Kepp i'm intrigued about your comment explian with more details

Comment: Rafael, what do you need to know? You can deploy asp.net web site "as is" - simply take all source files "as is" and put them to the web server including all directories. You don't need to compile anything, asp.net will compile the site itself when needed. Then you can change any source file and it is automatically recompiled. This is how asp.net worked since version 1, when precompilation was not even possible.