# Edit CS file on webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, code-behind, precompile

I'm running a website (.net 4.5) on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with IIS 7.5.  I'm using visual studio 2012 to create the web site and I published it from visual studio 2012.

Now my issue is that the lead guy at my job wants to be able to edit the cs files directly and have the changes propagate to the website without having to run visual studio or recompile the dll and copy it over to the web server.   I know this isn't the safest way, but I have no choice but to make it work.

That was how our old website/web servers was setup.  I wanted to make it more secure so I went the pre-compiled route and was told not too.

1. How can I change my current setup to allow this?
2. Do I have to republish everything?  The site is live and I can't interrupt it's use.
3. I have a class that handles the database connections.  Can this be edited the same way without recompiling?

Comment: Eventually, this is going to cause a nightmare for somebody.

Comment: I totally agree.  He says that worked for many years on the old server.  I have to leverage to say anything.  I have to do what is asked.

Comment: Fair enough, then I hope you get your answer (I'm surprised this has came from the lead by the way). EDIT: I suspect this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666122/how-do-you-compiling-cs-file-modification-on-a-deployed-website-is-it-possible

Comment: **Why** does he think he needs to edit `.cs` files? What parts of the site specifically does he want to edit? If it's just for editing the content, theming or menus, there are better solutions.

Comment: From what I understand from him he wants to be able to make changes if I'm not available without having to install visual studio.  He is an old school programmer.  This is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: the `LEAD GUY` as you have stated.. makes me wonder what he's leading .. this is the worst possible proposition in regards to coding that I have ever heard.. he's not a Lead Developer at all in my opinion.. please tell him to not apply for any position where I am working.. I would ask him seriously if he's familiar with `4GL-5GL` programming languages you must stand your ground on this .. it's obvious that he does not understand .net as well as IIS any file change recognized from the IIS web server for example changing the .config file will cause IIS to Reset.. not good...

Comment: I am curious what company you work for.. as I am sure others are too.. you seriously need to direct your so called Lead to `Stackoverflow` if worse comes to worse have him google `Jon Skeet` a .NET Master who could probably talk some sense into your lead..

Comment: There's probably someone over his head you can go to about this if he doesn't budge,  just make sure your case is clear, concise, and supported by best practices.  @DJKRAZE IIS doesn't reset when you change a web.config, just the application pool.

Comment: yes that's what I meant Paul.. which is still not good practice.. I was so caught up in trying to reply to this in a respectful way that I mis-stated but I think that others know what I mean.. as well as you Paul..respectfully speaking

Comment: BTW, whoever -1'd the question should reconsider.  There's nothing wrong with the way the question was asked or the information the OP is trying to get.  Just b/c it's not a best practice doesn't make it a poor question.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Just trying to clear it up for folks that don't have as much experience in the .NET environment as you do, so that they know there's such a thing as an IIS Reset, and a different thing that's an App Pool reset.

Comment: I agree Paul this is probably in my opinion seriously speaking one of the best questions I've seen on here in a while.. the OP is trying to do the correct thing but can't even do his job based on someone else's poor understanding of coding / best practices.. perhaps Jerry you should find as many Microsoft articles on this to support your argument as well

Comment: @Paul I agree.thanks for catching my misstated comment as well

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the site was working previously in a way that allowed the .cs files to be changed on the server, and that you then did the right thing by changing the site so that it is compiled first and only the .dll files deployed?

Answer (score 3):

Direct him to this thread where everyone is saying it's a horrible, horrible idea.

I mean, even in dynamic languages (ruby, node.js, etc) it's a best practice *not* to change the files in the running web server.

That said, there's a number of ways to do this.  Perhaps the easiest is to make use of code in the App_Code folder. Any class files located there will force a restart of the site with changes recompiled in by the framework.  I would recommend limiting stuff in there to things he really has a *need* to change, not just stuff he *wants* to change.

Comment: DeeMac,  I know the source control is what bothers me the most.  I'm using team foundation server and I like to keep my code clean.  I like seeing the history and comparing files.  This pretty much throws that all out the window.

Comment: I would ask him a simple question for example.. what happens when you delete a record from the database without any history.. how do you recover.. or how do you restore a backup without having an actual backup..? the same applies to TFS which is very good, you must have an audit trail .. just incase you need to roll back to a working version.. your lead needs to be terminated how the heck did he get his position.. he must adjust as well as change with the current times.. time never moves backwards always forward.... I feel for ya on this one `Jerry`